# sonar quality gate in azure pipelines for .net projects

Tags: .net, azure-devops, sonarqube, pull-request, quality-gate

We have set up sonar quality gate in our azure pipelines by using api key and using project_key as a paramater to fetch the quality gate status.

```
quality_gatesstatus=$(curl -u $sonar_token: https://$sonar_server/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=$sonar_project_key | grep -Po '"status": *\K"[^"]*"')
```

Here in the above code we are fetching the quality status and storing it in quality_gatestatus variable and later using the same variable value and giving condition like:

```
 if [ "$quality_gatesstatus" != "OK" ] && [ "$quality_gatesstatus" != "NONE" ]
 then
 echo "check sonar server and fix the issues"
 exit 1 
 fi
```

But we need in to run it on Pull requests i.e master/develop branch. So how to use "analysysid" or any PR_id to run it on our PRs. Anyone help me on this please.

Comment: We are trying to get result from different branches, like: branch=develop branch=master&projectKey=projectname –

Comment: Please anyone help me on this.